# QGIS GRASS plugin: r.composite quality loss

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

When using the r.composite tool within the GRASS plugin in QGIS, the result raster has a cell size of 150x150 while the input rasters have a cellsize of 30x30. Can this be overcome somehow or is this a consequence of the tool?

Data used: Landsat 8, QGIS version: 1.8.0, Operating system: Windows 7.

Comment: Use g.region to set the region settings, including resolution.

Comment: See also http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Computational_region

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use g.region to set the region settings, including resolution, i.e.

`g region -p rast=<your landsat raster> res=30`